# explain me what is happening here [c Character array + integer]

Tags: c, arrays, character

i saw this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[] = "       *      *     **   * * *  *";
    int line = 6, stop = 0, len = 8;
    for(line = 6; line > 0;line--){
        printf("%.*s\n", len, string + stop);
        stop = stop + len;
        --len;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

string is a character array, stop is an integer. how is %.*s selecting what to print? 
the out put is a tick mark made of starts:

```
       *
      *
     *
*   *
 * *
  *
```

Comment: There are only six iterations in that loop and two changing variables during that period of looping, something I would expect a pencil and some paper could easily assist in working out.

Comment: The `%.*s` format says to print at most `len` characters of the string argument.  `string + stop` provides the string argument, which begins at offset `stop` from the beginning of `string`.  This should give you total information about how C and the stdio library will handle this.  The rest is just walking through the loop iterations.

Comment: thanks, my question was mainly that string is a character array and stop is an integer.we are performing addition+ here...how?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and it will help explain what's going on...

```
include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char string[] = "       *      *     **   * * *  *";
    int line = 6, stop = 0, len = 8;
    for(line = 6; line > 0;line--){
        printf("print %d chars starting at position %d\n", len, stop);
        printf("%.*s\n", len, string + stop);
        stop = stop + len;
        --len;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

In the printf format ie `%.*s` the `.*` means that it is expecting an argument `len` in your case to specify how many character to print. the `string + stop` is specifying where to start printing from. I don't know who wrote this piece of code but it's a decent example of setting precision on strings.